# Amount to text conversion not found in odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

In odoo 10 we have `amount_to_text_en.py` file in `odoo/tools`. I was looking for similar file in odoo 11. But I can't find it . What to do ? 
Need I require to create that file in my custom module or is it present in odoo11 with different file name ? Please Help. Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the function you're looking for,

```py
 @api.multi
def amount_to_text(self, amount):
    self.ensure_one()
    def _num2words(number, lang):
        try:
            return num2words(number, lang=lang).title()
        except NotImplementedError:
            return num2words(number, lang='en').title()

    if num2words is None:
        logging.getLogger(__name__).warning("The library 'num2words' is missing, cannot render textual amounts.")
        return ""

    formatted = "%.{0}f".format(self.decimal_places) % amount
    parts = formatted.partition('.')
    integer_value = int(parts[0])
    fractional_value = int(parts[2] or 0)

    lang_code = self.env.context.get('lang') or self.env.user.lang
    lang = self.env['res.lang'].search([('code', '=', lang_code)])
    amount_words = tools.ustr('{amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(integer_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_unit_label,
                    )
    if not self.is_zero(amount - integer_value):
        amount_words += ' ' + _('and') + tools.ustr(' {amt_value} {amt_word}').format(
                    amt_value=_num2words(fractional_value, lang=lang.iso_code),
                    amt_word=self.currency_subunit_label,
                    )
    return amount_words
```

You can find this function in `base/res/res_currency.py`.

And you can call this function like below,

```py
words = self.currency_id.with_context(lang=self.partner_id.lang or 'es_ES').amount_to_text(amount_i).upper()
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Currently Iam working on another project will revert back when I start working back ..

Answer (score 3):

or simply add this span to your report:

```
<span t-if="doc.currency_id" t-esc="doc.currency_id.amount_to_text(doc.amount_total)"/>
```